# How to check angular radio button by default?

Tags: angular

I was trying to check an angular mat button by default! But it does not work !

```
    <div class="container shadow">
        <mat-radio-group>
          <mat-radio-button class="mat-button-custom" [checked]="true">Problems</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button class="mat-button-custom" [checked]="false">My Submission</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
     </div>
```

[image]

Another thing is how to change only the button color!When I override the mat-radio-button css with `background color: red` it also colors the button label ! But I only want to change the circle part that means only the button.

Comment: Default values rely on `ngModel` which you don't have. And you have a styling error it seems. Follow the guide on how to install material and it should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-radio-button class="mat-button-custom" checked>Problems</mat-radio-button>
```

This checks the radio button when the page loads. If you remove `checked` the button will not be checked.

Comment: Thanks ! It is what I was looking for. :D